# ClassX installation "codec not found" due to dependencies

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

ClassX is an interactive lecture streaming system developed in the Electrical Engineering Department at Stanford University.
Unlike conventional lecture capturing systems, ClassX requires very simple consumer-grade equipment and minimal human operation.

I faced problems during installing it, I hope you have a solution.

BTW: I successfully installed it 2 years ago, but now I think the problem as the dependencies and Ubuntu versions are different than the versions we used two years ago.

Detailed description of the problem:

- I'm using Ubuntu 12.04
- I followed the instructions @ [ClassX installation guide](http://classx.sourceforge.net/setup.html), and all steps till step 4 are successfully done (the encoder bin file generated).
- When trying to encode the video using the classX web system, it shows the encoding completed after few seconds.However, there are no tiles generated.
- I tried to execute the command at CX_log.txt, and the following error appears.

  > mahmoud@Mahmoud-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo perl /var/www/ClassXWebSystem/system/publishers/web/actions/encode.pl "/var/www/ClassXWebSystem/content/encoding/FALL_2013_2014/CS106A_FALL_2013_2014/lecSEven" "/var/www/ClassXWebSystem/content/encoding/FALL_2013_2014/CS106A_FALL_2013_2014/.encoding_1372706251" "/var/www/ClassXWebSystem/content/streaming/FALL_2013_2014/CS106A_FALL_2013_2014/lecSEven" "/var/www/ClassXWebSystem/system/publishers/bin" classx y n n
  >   [sudo] password for mahmoud: 
  >   00068.jpg
  >   ..
  >   .
  >   00068.mp4
  >   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/ClassXWebSystem/content/encoding/FALL_2013_2014/CS106A_FALL_2013_2014/.encoding_1372706251/00068.mp4':
  >     Metadata:
  >       major_brand     : isom
  >       minor_version   : 512
  >       compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  >       encoder         : Lavf52.39.0
  >     Duration: 00:02:30.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8141 kb/s
  >       Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8007 kb/s, 29.95 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 59.94 tbc
  >       Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
  >   Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/ClassXWebSystem/content/encoding/FALL_2013_2014/CS106A_FALL_2013_2014/.encoding_1372706251/stream0.mp4':
  >       Stream #0.0: Video: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, yuv420p, 640x360, q=32-36, 64 kb/s, 90k tbn, 14.99 tbc
  >   codec not found

Comment: You should find out what the actual `ffmpeg` command is and also provide the complete `ffmpeg` console output. Then properly format it by highlighting it and pressing `ctrl`+`k` or by using the code button.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `ffmpeg` exactly as stated in the guide, by compiling it from source with the required options?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.